# Moving and replcaing xml node based on condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

The following is my input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sample>
   <CDGCreateTree>
      <DST>
         <currentJobName>PQContactComplete</currentJobName>
         <AWD>
            <case>
               <CKEY>2016-03-28-04.21.07.535120T01</CKEY>
               <transaction>
                  <businessArea>CS2XAA</businessArea>
                  <type>ISSUE</type>
                  <status>CREATED</status>
                  <worklist>false</worklist>
                  <recordType>T</recordType>
                  <CFLG>2</CFLG>
                  <OUID>DT77214</OUID>
                  <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
                  <ITYP>MS Care1st Member</ITYP>
                  <ICT1>Demographic Change</ICT1>
                  <ICT2 />
                  <ICT3 />
                  <ICT4 />
                  <ICT5 />
                  <STRT>2016-03-28-14.52.37.000000</STRT>
                  <STPT>2016-03-28-14.53.00.000000</STPT>
                  <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
                  <RGRP>KISHG2D2</RGRP>
                  <RATH />
                  <RMEM>KKMTEST3000</RMEM>
                  <RPRV />
                  <RCLM />
                  <RTYP />
                  <MLOB>KISHG2</MLOB>
                  <UIID>20160328-145300-DT77214</UIID>
                  <CBDS />
                  <CEDS />
                  <ABDS />
                  <AEDS />
                  <FDID>KKMTEST3000</FDID>
                  <comments>%0D%0AMS%20Care1st%20Member%20-%20Demographic%20Change</comments>
               </transaction>
            </case>
            <case>
               <CKEY>2016-03-28-04.22.36.512120T01</CKEY>
               <transaction>
                  <businessArea>CS2XAA</businessArea>
                  <type>ISSUE</type>
                  <status>CREATED</status>
                  <worklist>false</worklist>
                  <recordType>T</recordType>
                  <CFLG>2</CFLG>
                  <OUID>DT77214</OUID>
                  <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
                  <ITYP>MS Correspondence</ITYP>
                  <ICT1>Adoption</ICT1>
                  <ICT2>Guardianship</ICT2>
                  <ICT3 />
                  <ICT4 />
                  <ICT5 />
                  <STRT>2016-03-28-14.53.00.000000</STRT>
                  <STPT>2016-03-28-14.53.25.000000</STPT>
                  <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
                  <RGRP>KISHG2D2</RGRP>
                  <RATH />
                  <RMEM>KKMTEST1300</RMEM>
                  <RPRV />
                  <RCLM />
                  <RTYP>PCP</RTYP>
                  <MLOB>KISHG2</MLOB>
                  <UIID>20160328-145325-DT77214</UIID>
                  <CBDS />
                  <CEDS />
                  <ABDS />
                  <AEDS />
                  <FDID>KKMTEST1300</FDID>
                  <comments>%0D%0AMS%20Correspondence%20-%20Adoption%0D%0AMS%20Correspondence%20-%20Guardianship</comments>
               </transaction>
            </case>
         </AWD>
      </DST>
   </CDGCreateTree>
   <CDGCreateTreeRequest>
      <newNode>
         <transaction relate="Y" id="2016-03-28-04.23.55.910120T01">
            <id>2016-03-28-04.23.55.910120T01</id>
            <createTime time="Y">2016-03-28T04:23:55:910120-05:00</createTime>
            <permission>Update</permission>
            <businessArea>CS2XAA</businessArea>
            <type>ISSUE</type>
            <workStep status="TOVBR">VBR Labeling</workStep>
            <status>TOVBR</status>
            <queue>SYSTEM</queue>
            <priority>999</priority>
            <priorityIncrease>0</priorityIncrease>
            <VIP>N</VIP>
            <assignedTo>SYSTEM</assignedTo>
            <lockedBy>SYSTEM</lockedBy>
            <amount>0.0000</amount>
            <amountType />
            <suspended>N</suspended>
            <process>Y</process>
            <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
            <iconName />
            <MLOB>KISHG2</MLOB>
            <STRT>2016-03-28-14.52.37.000000</STRT>
            <RMEM>KKMTEST3000</RMEM>
            <OUID>DT77214</OUID>
            <STPT>2016-03-28-14.53.00.000000</STPT>
            <FDID>KKMTEST3000</FDID>
            <ITYP>MS Care1st Member</ITYP>
            <ICT1>Demographic Change</ICT1>
            <RGRP>KISHG2D2</RGRP>
            <UIID>20160328-145300-DT77214</UIID>
            <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
            <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
            <CFLG>2</CFLG>
            <externalSystem>
               <host />
               <executable />
               <parameters />
               <procedure />
            </externalSystem>
            <commentsExist>Y</commentsExist>
         </transaction>
      </newNode>
   </CDGCreateTreeRequest>
</Sample>
```

My requirement is to verify if `//Sample/CDGCreateTreeRequest/newNode/transaction/UIID` value matches with the value of `//transaction/UIID` for the transaction nodes listed under the cases `//Sample/CDGCreateTree/DST/AWD/case`. If so, replace that particular `transaction` under case with the `transaction` `//Sample/CDGCreateTreeRequest/newNode/transaction`

The resultant xml should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sample>
   <CDGCreateTree>
      <DST>
         <currentJobName>PQContactComplete</currentJobName>
         <AWD>
            <case>
               <CKEY>2016-03-28-04.21.07.535120T01</CKEY>
               <transaction relate="Y" id="2016-03-28-04.23.55.910120T01">
                  <id>2016-03-28-04.23.55.910120T01</id>
                  <createTime time="Y">2016-03-28T04:23:55:910120-05:00</createTime>
                  <permission>Update</permission>
                  <businessArea>CS2XAA</businessArea>
                  <type>ISSUE</type>
                  <workStep status="TOVBR">VBR Labeling</workStep>
                  <status>TOVBR</status>
                  <queue>SYSTEM</queue>
                  <priority>999</priority>
                  <priorityIncrease>0</priorityIncrease>
                  <VIP>N</VIP>
                  <assignedTo>SYSTEM</assignedTo>
                  <lockedBy>SYSTEM</lockedBy>
                  <amount>0.0000</amount>
                  <amountType />
                  <suspended>N</suspended>
                  <process>Y</process>
                  <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
                  <iconName />
                  <MLOB>KISHG2</MLOB>
                  <STRT>2016-03-28-14.52.37.000000</STRT>
                  <RMEM>KKMTEST3000</RMEM>
                  <OUID>DT77214</OUID>
                  <STPT>2016-03-28-14.53.00.000000</STPT>
                  <FDID>KKMTEST3000</FDID>
                  <ITYP>MS Care1st Member</ITYP>
                  <ICT1>Demographic Change</ICT1>
                  <RGRP>KISHG2D2</RGRP>
                  <UIID>20160328-145300-DT77214</UIID>
                  <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
                  <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
                  <CFLG>2</CFLG>
                  <externalSystem>
                     <host />
                     <executable />
                     <parameters />
                     <procedure />
                  </externalSystem>
                  <commentsExist>Y</commentsExist>
               </transaction>
            </case>
            <case>
               <CKEY>2016-03-28-04.22.36.512120T01</CKEY>
               <transaction>
                  <businessArea>CS2XAA</businessArea>
                  <type>ISSUE</type>
                  <status>CREATED</status>
                  <worklist>false</worklist>
                  <recordType>T</recordType>
                  <CFLG>2</CFLG>
                  <OUID>DT77214</OUID>
                  <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
                  <ITYP>MS Correspondence</ITYP>
                  <ICT1>Adoption</ICT1>
                  <ICT2>Guardianship</ICT2>
                  <ICT3 />
                  <ICT4 />
                  <ICT5 />
                  <STRT>2016-03-28-14.53.00.000000</STRT>
                  <STPT>2016-03-28-14.53.25.000000</STPT>
                  <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
                  <RGRP>KISHG2D2</RGRP>
                  <RATH />
                  <RMEM>KKMTEST1300</RMEM>
                  <RPRV />
                  <RCLM />
                  <RTYP>PCP</RTYP>
                  <MLOB>KISHG2</MLOB>
                  <UIID>20160328-145325-DT77214</UIID>
                  <CBDS />
                  <CEDS />
                  <ABDS />
                  <AEDS />
                  <FDID>KKMTEST1300</FDID>
                  <comments>%0D%0AMS%20Correspondence%20-%20Adoption%0D%0AMS%20Correspondence%20-%20Guardianship</comments>
               </transaction>
            </case>
         </AWD>
      </DST>
   </CDGCreateTree>
   <CDGCreateTreeRequest>
      <newNode>
         <transaction relate="Y" id="2016-03-28-04.23.55.910120T01">
            <id>2016-03-28-04.23.55.910120T01</id>
            <createTime time="Y">2016-03-28T04:23:55:910120-05:00</createTime>
            <permission>Update</permission>
            <businessArea>CS2XAA</businessArea>
            <type>ISSUE</type>
            <workStep status="TOVBR">VBR Labeling</workStep>
            <status>TOVBR</status>
            <queue>SYSTEM</queue>
            <priority>999</priority>
            <priorityIncrease>0</priorityIncrease>
            <VIP>N</VIP>
            <assignedTo>SYSTEM</assignedTo>
            <lockedBy>SYSTEM</lockedBy>
            <amount>0.0000</amount>
            <amountType />
            <suspended>N</suspended>
            <process>Y</process>
            <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
            <iconName />
            <MLOB>KISHG2</MLOB>
            <STRT>2016-03-28-14.52.37.000000</STRT>
            <RMEM>KKMTEST3000</RMEM>
            <OUID>DT77214</OUID>
            <STPT>2016-03-28-14.53.00.000000</STPT>
            <FDID>KKMTEST3000</FDID>
            <ITYP>MS Care1st Member</ITYP>
            <ICT1>Demographic Change</ICT1>
            <RGRP>KISHG2D2</RGRP>
            <UIID>20160328-145300-DT77214</UIID>
            <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
            <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
            <CFLG>2</CFLG>
            <externalSystem>
               <host />
               <executable />
               <parameters />
               <procedure />
            </externalSystem>
            <commentsExist>Y</commentsExist>
         </transaction>
      </newNode>
   </CDGCreateTreeRequest>
</Sample>
```

Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to **XSL Identity Transforms** e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT).
And add spezial templates. You may try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AWD/case/transaction">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="new" select="//CDGCreateTreeRequest/newNode/transaction[UIID = $this/UIID]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test ="count($new) > 0">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$new" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's perfect.  +1 for quick response.